# Android animated and customizable Avatar as Fragment

Tags: android, animation, overlay, avatar

I am trying to build an App similar to this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhinohoney.buddyv2&hl=de&gl=US

The Avatar should be inside an Fragment, that then can be displayed as an overlay.
The Avatar can be then displayed over other apps.

I tought about using short video clips for the animations, but the avatar should be customizable. So its not really an option.

Thanks for ANY help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I thought about using a game engine, to get a fullscreen application and then remove the background to make it transparent.
But I dont think this is the right way...

Comment: Is it the right way to animate by little videos/Gif?